# Fitting multiple component GammaDistribution using PomeGranate

Tags: statistics, probability, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to generate a HMM model from some data, It should consist of 3 independent Gamma distributions, but i get the following error which i cannot seem to solve:

```
ValueError: shapes (909,1) and (909,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 909 (dim 0)
```

The follow is my setup and some generated data to work with:
from pomegranate import *
    import random
    import numpy as np

```
data = list(np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1,size = 1000))
data = np.asarray(data)
data = data.reshape(-1, 1)

model3 = HiddenMarkovModel.from_samples(GammaDistribution, n_components=3, X=data)
```

The setup works if i simply use a NormalDistribution instead

Answer (score 0):

This issue is adressed in the following GitHub topic:
https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/issues/490

Basically there is a bug in the latest version of pomegranate installed through pip or conda. You will have to pull the latest code from the git repository and install it. This is done (assuming Git is installed) executing following commands in a command prompt:

```
git clone https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate 
cd pomegranate 
python setup.py install
```